# Elasticsearch Head plugin browser does not show all index fields with Opensearch

Tags: opensearch, elasticsearch-head

I am using Opensearch v2.9 and trying to browse the index data using the Elasticsearch Head Chrome Extension. The issue is that the browser is not showing all the index fields. For any index, it is showing only 4 fields namely _index, _type, _id and score.

Has anyone else faced this? Is there a workaround/fix available?

Thanks in advance for any help.